# Not able to download specific URL in java

Tags: java, url, download, apache-commons

I am writing following program to download the URL using Apache Common-IO and I am getting ReadTimeOut exception,
Exception

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1456)
at com.touseef.stock.FileDownload.main(FileDownload.java:23)
```

Program

```
String urlStr = "https://www.nseindia.com/";
    File file = new File("C:\\User\\WorkSpace\\Output.txt");
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
        System.out.println("Successfully Completed.");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Other site are able to download. Please suggest. 
Using commons-io-2.6 jar.

Comment: Use the different method `copyURLToFile(URL source, File destination, int connectionTimeout,int readTimeout)` and specify longer time-outs. The error eccurs because of a too small readTimeout.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Used different method with longer timeouts, still same problem. Only to the specific website. Other sites are easily reachable. The mentioned website is seamlessly opening in web browser.

Comment: This problem is specific to this server. I assume that it requires certain HTTP headers, otherwise it just don't returns any result. hence you can't use `FileUtils.copyURLToFile` at all. You have to manually open up a HTTP connection,set the request headers and the proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this site is protected by some web gateway (DOS protection service like Akamai?). Clients seem to be fingerprinted by TLS connection and the HTTP request (headers) and only valid web browsers can connect to the site.

The following code uses [Apache commons http client 4.5](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html) and works at least at the moment:

```
    String urlStr = "https://www.nseindia.com/";
    File file = new File("C:\\User\\WorkSpace\\Output.txt");
    String userAgent = "-";

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent(userAgent).build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlStr);
    httpget.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    httpget.addHeader("Cookie", "");

    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(body);
        Files.writeString(file.toPath(), body);
    }
```

A request that e.g works from within Firefox does not work from Java (because the TLS connection with protocols and ciphers is different). I tried a few combinations using Apache commons http client. but is also fails (even though the same request works from Fiddler).

Hence using this web site from within Java is extremely difficult and even the code above works at the moment, the protection system can be adapted at any time so that it won't work again.

I would assume that such a site provides an API dedicated for program usage. Contact them and ask, that is the only advice I can give to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got fixed by using ui4j and jsoup api.